# Скрипт Python не кликает в игровом окне

Tags: python, click, ctypes, pyautogui, мышь

Пишу бота. 
Есть некое окно игры, куда не проходят клики из Python. 
Пробовал и ctypes, и autopy и pyautogui. 
Не хочет и всё, вне окна игры работает замечательно
Мало того, что он в самой игре не может ничего кликнуть, так даже и окно с игрой свернуть таким способом не получается.

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? И как победить эту заразу?

```
# Пример с использованием ctypes
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0,0) # left down
ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0,0) # left up
```

```
# Пример с использованием autopy
import autopy
autopy.mouse.click()
```

```
# Пример с использованием pyautogui
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click()
```

UPD:
win32 api Тоже не работает

Comment: в фул скрин не работает или в оконном режиме тоже ?

Comment: @Интик  так и так.. Без разницы, в любом случае не работает

Comment: JUST RUN THE PROGRAM (IDLE) AS ADMIN тоже не помогает ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489013/simulate-python-keypresses-for-controlling-a-game  и это не помогает ?

Comment: @Интик от админа не работает так же, англоязычный стаковерфлоу не особо помог, ибо мне нужна именно симуляция нажатия левой кнопки мыши, а коды я нашёл только на клавиши клавиатуры. Игра - Piratia Online, или Tales of Pirates, или Pirates King Online (у неё несколько названий) информации ни о движке, ни вообще какой-либо информации я не нашёл, сам проект закрылся ещё в 2016 году.

Comment: Ты уже нашёл решение проблемы? Или вопрос остаётся открытым? У меня абсолютно такая же проблема,  только уже с клавишными нажатиями на клавиатуре, не знаю что делать, идентично всё как и у тебя, но игра другая

Comment: @GreenPy Привет. Я давно забросил эту идею, но на сколько я помню мне удалось кликнуть каким-то из моих способов в окне игры, когда я добавил к проекту "ioport.dll". Как именно уже не вспомню, копни в эту сторону (саму dll взял из архива кликера "clickermann". Кстати, этот кликер отлично кликал в самой игре)

Comment: @GreenPy вы решили эту проблему? Если да то можете подсказать как вы это сделали?

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn как с тобой можно связаться? тоже работаю над ботов для Tales of Pirates

Comment: @Leonid https://t.me/tpoWtfisgoingon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это может быть связано с directX. попробуй использовать библиотеку pydirectinput

```
import pydirectinput
pydirectinput.moveTo(100, 150)
pydirectinput.click()
pydirectinput.click(200, 220)
pydirectinput.move(None, 10)
pydirectinput.doubleClick()
pydirectinput.press('esc')
pydirectinput.keyDown('shift')
pydirectinput.keyUp('shift')
```

Comment: Я вернулся к этому вопросу снова (тут нужно удивиться). И это сработало, спасибо большое.